# unnable to click element in selenium webdriver using phantomjs python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been using phantomjs along with selenium's webdriver in order to parse a page off it's information. The problem is in order to keep parsing I need to click the next button since the information is javascript generated, I've used the following lines

```
next_page = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/descendant::a[@title='Siguiente'][1]")
webdriver.ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(next_page).click()
```

in the following context (url is actual parsed page)

```
from selenium import webdriver
PHANTOMJS_PATH = './phantomjs/phantomjs'
FARMACIA_URL = 'http://www.chedraui.com.mx/index.php/ajusco/endeca/category/view/id/457/'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(PHANTOMJS_PATH)
browser.get(FARMACIA_URL)
```

I have not gotten an error from the xpath not existing or any other error, the page simply does not refresh inside the program when clicked.

I have tried using *browser.implicitly_wait(4)* before and after the action and substituting the *click()* method with *send_keys("\n")*. There seem to be some more elaborated solutions involving javascript events but I have yet to try them and I'm a bit tired.

Any clues as to why this behavior is happening and how to fix it are much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `perform()` on `ActionChains` functions

```
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(next_page).click().perform()
```